# Llenar un DropDownList con Fecha. ASPX C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

hola!
¿Cómo podría llenar un DropDownList que me almacene las últimas cinco fechas anteriores empezando por, por ejemplo, hoy?

**28/06/2018**
27/06/2018
25/06/2018

Y al seleccionar una fecha me cargue un GridView que esta enlazado con una base de datos; una tabla que contiene una columna con la fecha en el formato 2018/06/26.
Se que puedo hacer con un WHILE igualar las fechas y mostrarlas, pero no tengo idea cómo cargar las fechas en el DropDownList. Obvio éstas tienen que estar actualizándose dependiendo del día actual.

Comment: WebForms o Mvc?

Comment: Aplicación web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando el metodo `DateTime#AddDay` puedes lograrlo. Este metodo lo que hace es que  agrega/resta un dia de la fecha y retorna una instancia con la nueva fecha:

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) // 20-06-2018
```

Entonces solo tendrias que agregar un `for` y agregar las fechas al `DropDownList`:

```
for(var i = 0; i > -5;i--)
{
   fechasDropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i).ToString("dd/MM/yyy")));
}
```

Comment: Ok, pero si requiero que la fecha de ese día sea la primera que me muestre?

Comment: @Elizabeth, acabo de actualizar la respuesta con lo que. Dale una mirada. Solo tienes que hacer que el bucle descienda.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!